Can i use this to power my router via power bank
My power bank is redmi 18w 20000mah
It has 12v ==1.5a output, so can I use this cable to power the 12v router


The ad, https://www.amazon.com/Xiaomi-20000mAh-Capacity-External-Compatible/dp/B08LN1YV1X, clearly states 5.1 volt output. If it can output higher voltage on USB-C, you would need the correct "handshake" between the router's input and the power bank. Easiest is to get a 12 V sealed lead-acid battery and 12 V trickle (standby) charger -- in fact, some routers are already set up for that! Also, you might find the 20 A-h rating more than a  bit optimistic in your intended use -- at best, it would be 20 A-h at 3.7 V, equivalent to a 7 A-h 12 V battery.

All routers have serial pads, with many having a serial header for USB-TTL, and if your router has one on its board, all you need to power it is the correct voltage USB-TTL cable  (either 3.3V or 5V, and an FTDI chip is highly recommended since they're the most reliable). The Audio Jack versions of the USB-TTL cable can't be used since they lack the VCC+ wire which is what provides power to the board via the USB-TTL cable (it's important to use either the DC jack or the USB-TTL header, not both).

(Cont'd...) Another option would be to use a DC to DC converter board with a USB power only cable as an input from the USB on the powerbank, outputting to a two wire cable with the correct size DC jack for the router. This will also allow tuning the voltage and amperage to specifically what the DC wall adapter outputs.

No. Your power bank does not "have 12 V". Higher voltages are only switched to after the connected device requests them, either using magic resistors or, more likely, after active negotiation using USB Power Delivery or similar proprietary technologies.
Simply rigging a USB connector with a barrel connector will not work.

The way you show on that pic, wiring GND/Vbus from USB-A connector (5V) direct into 12V barrel, nope. Maybe, just maybe, if you find a USB-C power bank, which is 12V output capable, use a trigger module to trigger a 12V output, and wire that into your router, assuming high enough output current capability on both the power bank side and the trigger module, THEN you should be fine.
Disclaimer - the Amazon link is just the first module i found there using their search, i didn't use it myself, and cannot recommend or review it.

I just saw the power bank part - as another commenter touched on, power banks don't usually put out 12V (some do), so you probably won't get 12V out of that. Even if it can negotiate 12V, that is most likely a USB PD type function, so it won't work over USB-A. You'd be better off getting a dedicated adapater, unless you can find something that does 12V out through USB-A (I'm not sure anyone is making them outside of DIY hacks)
Most likely, the wires are fine. 1.5 isn't a lot of watts and it looks like those are both fairly standard wires used for that purpose (they're think but this isn't a lot of current). As long as those solder joints are sound, you should be good. If in doubt, fire it up and just check the joint (which I hope you will wrap with electrical tape or similar), warm is okay, too hot to keep your finger on more than a second is probably too hot and either the joint or skimpy wires are likely causing the problem.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
